# Hiding an embedded aframe scene

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I want to programmatically hide and show my embedded aframe scene. The scene is hidden when the website is loaded, however I only get it to work with a delay like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("scene-page").setAttribute("hidden", ""); }, 500);
}
```

When I don't add this delay, the scene remains hidden, even after setting it to 'visible' again. Specifically, the size of the canvas seems to be resized to 0px:

```
<canvas class="a-canvas a-grab-cursor" data-aframe-canvas="true" width="0" height="0" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></canvas>
```

The only way to make it visible then is to resize the browser window, which then seems to resize the canvas.

Is there a better way to hide the scene without the delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i see (posts like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200627/draw-in-hidden-html5-canvas-element-doesnt-work), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949899/canvas-in-a-div-with-display-none-does-not-work)), if you set `display: none` before the entire canvas loads, the `canvas` / `renderer` / `camera` properties won't set up properly.

I tried waiting for the `a-scene`'s `loaded`/`renderstart` event, `window.onload`, and the internal entities, still it seems to mess up the canvas settings.

The reason why it's working when you resize the window is because the scene has a listener for `resize` which updates all of these accordingly with the canvas `width` / `height`. I'm not sure if its possible to call the `resize` manually.

Check it out [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aframevr/aframe/master/dist/aframe-v0.8.0.js) -> just search for `this.resize`, there are 3 hits, one in the `a-scene`.

---

It seems easier and safer to place a blank `<div>` if front of the a-frame canvas with a fixed position, which will be switched from `display: none` to `block`. live fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/64kwz0kn/55/) !

Once the scene is up and running, You can toggle its `display` all you want though! live fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/64kwz0kn/58/) !